# If a contact is in Trash (because they were merged) but the person with matching details fills in Membership what is a good outcome

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, duplicate-contacts, deleted

Scenario was Contact A had email mydomain.co.nz

Contact A then filled out a Join/Renew (not using checksum) and used mydomain.nz

Result was Contact B was created.

Those contacts were later identified and merged while keeping Contact A with their original .co.nz email. Contact B was hence in Trash with the .nz email.

Contact then again renewed by using the .nz email - and hence the dedupe rules matched with the contact in Trash and added the membership to that record ie Contact B.

Seems like this is a fuzzy area, if a Contact is in Trash, but meets the required 'matching rules' what should happen to eg Contributions and Memberships or any other data.

Comment: This seems like a bug if it's the member person doing the renewing, and it should create a new contact, no? It might not be dedupe rules causing the issue - it might be separate membership renewal code not excluding deleted contacts in its search.

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'separate renewal code' - if it helps, afaik the person involved just filled in a form as anon.

Comment: I mean there are code functions that handle dedupe, and this doesn't sound like the exact same code functions get run, rather, it's a separate set of code that uses different business logic. I say that because dedupe, e.g. when run from Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts, doesn't match on deleted (at least on dmaster demo). So, this seems like a bug in the (likely) separate business logic code that handles membership signups where it isn't excluding deleted. In any case, I would expect the behavior to be that it excludes deleted.

Comment: When the contact renewed again and the membership was added to Contact B, was Contact B moved out of Trash or left there?

Comment: Left in trash..

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the Contact in Trash to be ignored by the dedupe rules, so if the dedupe rules don't match a (non-Trash) contact then a new one would be created.

If you add the Contact B .nz address as an extra email on Contact A then with the right dedupe rule you could avoid repeated new contacts.